# Limiting the number of objects in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The answer is **not capped collections** because I want to update that data real time, so I just did it and got errors everytime about "you can't change the collection size etc." So... I want to limit object number in my collection. For example, if I set the limit to 3 and if I already have 3 objects in my collection I want the old one out.

New item: 9

Collection before update: 3, 2, 7
Collection after update: 2, 7, 9

Comment: unfortunately mongodb does not provide something for this you can always manually delete old ones though also you can use ttls for time based auto deletion

Comment: You can use [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html) to control (or limit) the number of documents within a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can slice it.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/

Start with

```
{ "_id" : 1, "scores" : [ 40, 50, 60 ] }
```

Then do a slice with 3 more items...

```
db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
       scores: {
         $each: [ 80, 78, 86 ],
         $slice: -5
       }
     }
   }
)
```

Will only keep the last 5 items.

```
{ "_id" : 1, "scores" : [  50,  60,  80,  78,  86 ] }
```

So in your case, just slice (-3)

Comment: I think he asks collectionwise which is not possible afaik

Comment: I think I will agree with you on that. What he describes does really make no sense, even as a NoSQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Insert the new document
- Run the query to determine the oldest document you don't want
- Delete all documents aged the oldest or older

... in a transaction.